# Protractor upload stuck when filesearch pops up

Tags: protractor, image-uploading

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the code below:

```
it('should upload a photo', function(){

        var photo = './photos/et-test.jpeg',
            exactPhoto = path.resolve(__dirname, photo);
        var form = element(by.id('fileupload'));
        var upload = element(by.css('input[type = "file"]'));
        var addFiles = element(by.cssContainingText('.btn.btn-success.fileinput-button.mb-10','Add files...'));
        var uploadBtn = element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.start.mt-20'));

        element(by.cssContainingText('.inline_link','Upload more album photos now')).click();
        element(by.id('secondary_upload_link')).click();


        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(addFiles), 5000);
        addFiles.click();

        upload.sendKeys(exactPhoto);

        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(uploadBtn), 5000);
        uploadBtn.click();

        expect(element(by.css('.table')).getText()).toBe('Upload Finised');

    });
```

I keep getting stuck on the filesearch popup and receive this error:

> Message:
>       Failed: Wait timed out after 5006ms

Is there anything lacking or should've been done based on the flow of my code?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly you are seeing a popup window when uploading a file. Can you try the following capability in your conf (assuming you are using Chrome)

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
        download: {
          'prompt_for_download': false,
          'directory_upgrade': true,
          'default_directory': 'src/test/javascript/e2e/downloads'(or where ever you prefer)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah no. You see, this line opens up a file upload window:


`addFiles.click();`

and by the time in displays, the wait timed out will end the execution not continuing to:

`upload.sendKeys(exactPhoto);`

Comment: Is that click necessary? It should be possible to upload the files without opening the  file window, just using the send keys approach you are already using.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you don't need to click on it, just `sendKeys()` for this `input` element
2. Sometimes it needs to make this `input` visible. Just try like that (it works in my case for await/async protractor):

`private addAttachment = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'))`

`await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].style.height = '1px'; arguments[0].style.width = '1px'; arguments[0].style.opacity = 1; arguments[0].style.display = 'inline'; arguments[0].style.overflow = 'visible'", this.addAttachment)`

`await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].focus();", await this.addAttachment.getWebElement())`

`await this.addAttachment.sendKeys(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var photo = './photos/et-test.jpg',
exactPhoto = path.resolve(__dirname, photo);
var form = element(by.id('fileupload')); ///Users/leochardc/ET/photos/et-test.jpg
var upload = element(by.css('.fileupload_section input[type = "file"]'));
var addFiles = element(by.cssContainingText('.btn.btn-success.fileinput-button.mb-10','Add files...'));
var uploadBtn = element(by.css('.btn.btn-primary.start.mt-20'));
var uploadFinished = element(by.css('.fileupload_section .text-center p'));

browser.get(url);
element(by.cssContainingText('.inline_link','Upload more album photos now')).click();
element(by.id('secondary_upload_link')).click();


browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(addFiles), 5000);
// addFiles.click();

upload.sendKeys(exactPhoto);

var previewPic = element(by.css('.fileupload_section.fileupload_files'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(previewPic), 5000);

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(uploadBtn), 5000);
uploadBtn.click();

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(uploadFinished), 30000);

expect(uploadFinished.getText()).toBe('Upload Finished');
```